# Unable to render a mdx component in my Next.js 13 project

Tags: next.js, next.js13, mdxjs

I am developing a MDX powered blog using Next.js 13 `app` directory. I have followed all the steps at the following URL to set up the `@next/mdx` package.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/mdx

Currently my Next.js project is set up like this:

[image]

Inside the `app` directory, I have a directory named `blog` and inside the `blog` directory I have a directory named `my-first-blog-post`. Inside `my-first-blog-post`, I have two files: `hello.mdx` and `page.tsx`.

Here is my `hello.mdx` file:

**hello.mdx**

```
Hello, Next.js!
 
You can import and use React components in MDX files.
```

Here is my `page.tsx` file:

**page.tsx**

```
import HelloWorld from "./hello.mdx";

export default function Page() {
  return <HelloWorld />;
}
```

Note that I have a file named `mdx-components.tsx` in the root directory of my project. Here is the `mdx-components.tsx` file:

**mdx-components.tsx**

```
import type { MDXComponents } from "mdx/types";

// This file allows you to provide custom React components
// to be used in MDX files. You can import and use any
// React component you want, including components from
// other libraries.

// This file is required to use MDX in `app` directory.
export function useMDXComponents(components: MDXComponents): MDXComponents {
  return {
    // Allows customizing built-in components, e.g. to add styling.
    // h1: ({ children }) => <h1 style={{ fontSize: "100px" }}>{children}</h1>,
    ...components,
  };
}
```

Here is my `next.config.js` file:

**next.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    mdxRs: true,
  },
};

const withMDX = require("@next/mdx")();
module.exports = withMDX(nextConfig);
```

**The issue**

When I visit `/blog/my-first-blog-post` route, I get a blank page.

[image]

Instead I should see the following:

```
Hello, Next.js!
 
You can import and use React components in MDX files.
```

What am I doing wrong?

I also don't understand the following error messages in the browser:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'inAmpMode' of '(0 , _react.useContext)(...)' as it is null.
    at Html (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js:723:13)
    at renderWithHooks (file://C:\Users\Delhivery\Desktop\hemanta-nextjs-blog\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:8677:16)
    at renderIndeterminateComponent (file://C:\Users\Delhivery\Desktop\hemanta-nextjs-blog\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:8751:15)
    at renderElement (file://C:\Users\Delhivery\Desktop\hemanta-nextjs-blog\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:8986:7)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (file://C:\Users\Delhivery\Desktop\hemanta-nextjs-blog\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:9152:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (file://C:\Users\Delhivery\Desktop\hemanta-nextjs-blog\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:9124:14)
    at finishClassComponent (file://C:\Users\Delhivery\Desktop\hemanta-nextjs-blog\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:8707:3)
    at renderClassComponent (file://C:\Users\Delhivery\Desktop\hemanta-nextjs-blog\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:8715:3)
    at renderElement (file://C:\Users\Delhivery\Desktop\hemanta-nextjs-blog\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:8983:7)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (file://C:\Users\Delhivery\Desktop\hemanta-nextjs-blog\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:9152:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (file://C:\Users\Delhivery\Desktop\hemanta-nextjs-blog\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:9124:14)
    at renderContextProvider (file://C:\Users\Delhivery\Desktop\hemanta-nextjs-blog\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:8950:3)
    at renderElement (file://C:\Users\Delhivery\Desktop\hemanta-nextjs-blog\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:9063:11)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (file://C:\Users\Delhivery\Desktop\hemanta-nextjs-blog\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:9152:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (file://C:\Users\Delhivery\Desktop\hemanta-nextjs-blog\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:9124:14)
    at renderContextProvider (file://C:\Users\Delhivery\Desktop\hemanta-nextjs-blog\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:8950:3)
    at renderElement (file://C:\Users\Delhivery\Desktop\hemanta-nextjs-blog\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:9063:11)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (file://C:\Users\Delhivery\Desktop\hemanta-nextjs-blog\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:9152:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (file://C:\Users\Delhivery\Desktop\hemanta-nextjs-blog\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:9124:14)
    at retryTask (file://C:\Users\Delhivery\Desktop\hemanta-nextjs-blog\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:9619:5)
    at performWork (file://C:\Users\Delhivery\Desktop\hemanta-nextjs-blog\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:9690:7)
    at <unknown> (file://C:\Users\Delhivery\Desktop\hemanta-nextjs-blog\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:10065:14)
    at scheduleWork (file://C:\Users\Delhivery\Desktop\hemanta-nextjs-blog\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:78:3)
    at startWork (file://C:\Users\Delhivery\Desktop\hemanta-nextjs-blog\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:10064:5)
    at <unknown> (file://C:\Users\Delhivery\Desktop\hemanta-nextjs-blog\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:10188:5)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.renderToReadableStream (file://C:\Users\Delhivery\Desktop\hemanta-nextjs-blog\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:10137:10)
    at renderToString (file://C:\Users\Delhivery\Desktop\hemanta-nextjs-blog\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:82:55)
    at <unknown> (file://C:\Users\Delhivery\Desktop\hemanta-nextjs-blog\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:914:112)
    at NextTracerImpl.trace (file://C:\Users\Delhivery\Desktop\hemanta-nextjs-blog\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\trace\tracer.js:90:20)
    at renderToHTML (file://C:\Users\Delhivery\Desktop\hemanta-nextjs-blog\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:914:57)
    at async doRender (file://C:\Users\Delhivery\Desktop\hemanta-nextjs-blog\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1054:26)
    at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.incrementalCache.incrementalCache (file://C:\Users\Delhivery\Desktop\hemanta-nextjs-blog\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1182:28)
    at async (file://C:\Users\Delhivery\Desktop\hemanta-nextjs-blog\node_modules\next\dist\server\response-cache\index.js:99:36)
2client.js:1 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
console.error @ client.js:1
react.development.js:1626 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useReducer')
    at Object.useReducer (react.development.js:1626:1)
    at ReactDevOverlay (client.js:857:956)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:25738:1)
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:266:1)
    at flushWork (scheduler.development.js:239:1)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (scheduler.development.js:533:1)
client.js:1 Warning: An error occurred during hydration. The server HTML was replaced with client content in <div>. 

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error
console.error @ client.js:1
2client.js:1 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
console.error @ client.js:1
react.development.js:1626 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useReducer')
    at Object.useReducer (react.development.js:1626:1)
    at ReactDevOverlay (client.js:857:956)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25850:1)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:25750:1)
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:266:1)
    at flushWork (scheduler.development.js:239:1)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (scheduler.development.js:533:1)
client.js:1 The above error occurred in the <ReactDevOverlay> component:

    at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-dev-overlay/dist/client.js:858:919)
    at Container (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:92:1)
    at AppContainer (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:196:11)
    at Root (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:374:11)

React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, Container.
console.error @ client.js:1
client.js:1 Warning: Container: Error boundaries should implement getDerivedStateFromError(). In that method, return a state update to display an error message or fallback UI.
    at Container (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:92:1)
    at AppContainer (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:196:11)
    at Root (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:374:11)
console.error @ client.js:1
react-dom.development.js:19849 Uncaught Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.
    at updateHostRoot (react-dom.development.js:19849:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21615:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25850:1)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:25750:1)
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:266:1)
    at flushWork (scheduler.development.js:239:1)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (scheduler.development.js:533:1)
index.js:447 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cancel rendering route
    at lastRenderReject (index.js:447:27)
    at eval (index.js:438:13)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at doRender (index.js:436:27)
    at renderError (index.js:272:16)
    at Object.fn (index.js:229:13)
    at Container.componentDidCatch (index.js:95:20)
    at Container.callback (react-dom.development.js:18768:1)
    at callCallback (react-dom.development.js:13923:1)
    at commitUpdateQueue (react-dom.development.js:13944:1)
    at commitLayoutEffectOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:23364:1)
    at commitLayoutMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24688:1)
    at commitLayoutEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24674:1)
    at commitLayoutEffects (react-dom.development.js:24612:1)
    at commitRootImpl (react-dom.development.js:26823:1)
    at commitRoot (react-dom.development.js:26682:1)
    at finishConcurrentRender (react-dom.development.js:25892:1)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:25809:1)
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:266:1)
    at flushWork (scheduler.development.js:239:1)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (scheduler.development.js:533:1)
2client.js:1 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
console.error @ client.js:1
react.development.js:1626 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useReducer')
    at Object.useReducer (react.development.js:1626:1)
    at ReactDevOverlay (client.js:857:956)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopConcurrent (react-dom.development.js:26543:1)
    at renderRootConcurrent (react-dom.development.js:26505:1)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:25738:1)
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:266:1)
    at flushWork (scheduler.development.js:239:1)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (scheduler.development.js:533:1)
2client.js:1 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
console.error @ client.js:1
react.development.js:1626 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useReducer')
    at Object.useReducer (react.development.js:1626:1)
    at ReactDevOverlay (client.js:857:956)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25850:1)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:25750:1)
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:266:1)
    at flushWork (scheduler.development.js:239:1)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (scheduler.development.js:533:1)
client.js:1 The above error occurred in the <ReactDevOverlay> component:

    at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-dev-overlay/dist/client.js:858:919)
    at Container (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:92:1)
    at AppContainer (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:196:11)
    at Root (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:374:11)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
console.error @ client.js:1
react-dom.development.js:26923 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useReducer')
    at Object.useReducer (react.development.js:1626:1)
    at ReactDevOverlay (client.js:857:956)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25850:1)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:25750:1)
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:266:1)
    at flushWork (scheduler.development.js:239:1)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (scheduler.development.js:533:1)
```

Comment: have you got any solution